# yii error while excecuting custom command

Tags: php, yii

I am getting the below error below when I run my custom `yiic` command in the terminal.

I can't seem to track down the cause of this error, can anyone point me in the right direction. I know the DB is working fine as other parts of the app work.

```
<?php

    class RbacCommand extends CConsoleCommand
    {
        private $_authManager;

        public function getHelp()
        {
            return "<<<EOD

            USAGE
                rbac

            DESCRIPTION
                This command generates an initial RBAC authorization hierarchy.

            EOD";
        }

        public function run($args)
        {
            if(($this->_authManager=Yii::app()->authManager)===null)
            {
                echo "Error: an authorization manager, named 'authManager' must be configured to use this command.\n";
                echo "If you already added 'authManager' component in applicaton configuration,\n";
                echo "please quit and re-enter the yiic shell.\n";
                return;
            }

            echo "This command will create three roles: Owner, Member, and Reader and the following permissions:\n";
            echo "create, read, update and delete user\n";
            echo "create, read, update and delete project\n";
            echo "create, read, update and delete issue\n";
            echo "Would you like to continue? [Yes|No]";

            if(!strncasecmp(trim(fgets(STDIN)),'y',1))
            {
                $this->_authManager->clearAll();

                $this->_authManager->createOperation("createUser","create a new user");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("readUser","read user profile information");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("updateUser","update a users information");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("deleteUser","remove a user from a project");

                $this->_authManager->createOperation("createProject","create a new project");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("readProject","read project information");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("updateProject","update project information");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("deleteProject","delete a project");

                $this->_authManager->createOperation("createIssue","create a new issue");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("readIssue","read issue information");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("updateIssue","update issue information");
                $this->_authManager->createOperation("deleteIssue","delete a issue");

                $role=$this->_authManager->createRole("member");
                $role->addChild("reader");
                $role->addChild("createIssue");
                $role->addChild("updateIssue");
                $role->addChild("deleteIssue");

                $role=$this->_authManager->createRole("owner");
                $role->addChild("reader");
                $role->addChild("member");
                $role->addChild("createUser");
                $role->addChild("updateUser");
                $role->addChild("deleteUser");
                $role->addChild("createProject");
                $role->addChild("updateProject");
                $role->addChild("deleteProject");
            }
        }
    }

?>



users-MacBook-Air:protected user$ ./yiic shell ../index.php
Yii Interactive Tool v1.1 (based on Yii v1.1.2)
Please type 'help' for help. Type 'exit' to quit.
>> rbac

Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php on line 302
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:267
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(242): CDbConnection->open()
#1 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(221): CDbConnection->setActive(true)
#2 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(363): CDbConnection->init()
#3 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/web/auth/CDbAuthManager.php(570): CModule->getComponent('db')
#4 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/web/auth/CDbAuthManager.php(69): CDbAuthManager->getDbConnection()
#5 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(363): CDbAuthManager->init()
#6 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(86): CModule->getComponent('authManager')
#7 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/trackstar/protected/commands/shell/RbacCommand.php(22): CModule->__get('authManager')
#8 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/cli/commands/ShellCommand.php(144): RbacCommand->run(Array)
#9 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/cli/commands/ShellCommand.php(99): ShellCommand->runShell()
#10 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(62): ShellCommand->run(Array)
#11 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(88): CConsoleCommandRunner->run(Array)
#12 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(135): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#13 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/yii/framework/yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#14 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/trackstar/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once('/Users/user/Dro...')
#15 /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/trackstar/protected/yiic(4): require_once('/Users/user/Dro...')
#16 {main}
>>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

Change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in your connection string.

OR:

Add `unix_socket=/path/to/socket` in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Yii uses different configuration files in `protected/config/`:

- `main.php`for the web,
- `console.php` for the CLI,
- `test.php` for the (unit) tests.

You probably configured your DB connection in `main.php` but forgot to do it in `console.php`.