# MAMP upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, yii, mamp

I am upgrading MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 for MAMP

Do I need to get a new .so file for php integration with 5.6

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/conf

So, I added the change in php.ini in above directory to use /tmp/mysql.sock which is used by MySQL 5.6

But, even after this phpinfo page still shows MySQL 5.5 and also php code is always trying to connect to MySQL 5.5

I find that both MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6 can run together on port 3306 since they work on different sock files. MySQL 5.6 has /tmp/mysql.sock and MySQL 5.5 has /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Need to read from MySQL 5.6 instead of 5.5 database from php for upgrade..

**EDIT**

I tried created a Soft Link - 
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

But this gives error in php ->
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: I think that the port is the problem, check MySQL 5.6 log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this post solved it. All I had to do was change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in yii while configuring db module

[yii error while excecuting custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949319/yii-error-while-excecuting-custom-command)